# phpDocumentor page-level docBlock in html included file

Tags: phpdoc

I'm using the tool from phpdoc.org and i'm stuck when I have a PHP file such as header.inc.php with only HTML inside.

```
<?php
    /**
    * Header content
    *
    * @author  My name
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="no-js"> 
    <head>
...
```

I get an error in my phpdoc "No page-level DocBlock was found in file...". I googled it but I didnt find any user with my case.

How to fix that error? Any tips are welcome.

Thank's!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok anwser found: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/695

TL;DR: At the moment, it's not fixed, just ignore theses warnings.

Comment: Tip found, put a namespace like: namespace ns;

Comment: How do you do that ? Can you give an example ? And how will the page level docblock show in the documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this posting and though it's older, I thought I would add my two cents. While sylouuu is correct about placing a namespace directly after the your intended page-level DocBlock, I believe that it is now required to place the '@package' tag in the DocBlock. There is some caution here when dealing with logical versus hierarchical 'packages'. This behavior is basically dependent upon which version of PHPDocumentor you are using.

From: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_elements.pkg.html
"In phpDocumentor version 1.2.2, a Page-level DocBlock is the first DocBlock in a file if it contains a @package tag."

And at https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/910 it can be read that as recently as a month ago, the issue of page-level DocBlocks in files with no PHP code/nodes is still being worked. Thus, as sylouuu stated about adding a namespace, once you do this, you have an documentable element and your problem should be resolved. Additionally, since most likely no documentation for the page will be created without having a node present, this allows your html-only file to have its documentation created.

Hope it helps!
dw