# Page-level docblocks and phpdocumentor templates

Tags: php, documentation-generation, docblocks, phpdocumentor2

I'm having a really hard time to get phpDocumentor 2 working.

I have several files in procedural style, that must be documented. The only I found to do that is to use [page-level docblocks](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_elements.pkg.html), but it seems, that they don't work anymore correctly in phpDocumentor version 2.

[A related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622548/phpdocumentor-page-level-docblock-in-html-included-file) shows that others run in the same problem. In this question there are two suggestions:

1. Add a `namespace` to the files that should be documented
2. As of [phpDoc issue 910](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/910) use the template `abstract` or `new-black`

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get work either one.

1. When I add the namespace, the namespace itself shows up in the doc, but not the content of the docblock.
2. When I choose another template (I tried `zend`, `abstract` and `new-black`) whith the phar version of phpDoc 2, I get the error `PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::transformToUri(): No stylesheet associated to this object in phar`. Apparently this is a [known problem](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/pull/1269).

EDIT:

I'm a step further. I installed the PEAR version of phpDocumentor, and tried out each available template. But I'm still far from reaching the goal: page-level docblocks in the generated documentation.
The templates fall in two categories :

- `clean`, `responsive`, `responsive-twig` and `old-ocean`: They do not output page-level docblocks in the generated documentation.
- `abstract`, `new-black` and `zend`: They have a *doc by file* section, which show the expected file-level documentation. But they miss several ressources (.js files and images), therefore they look all the same, and do not work correctly (the navigation pane does not have expand-collapse behavior). I looked in their git repository, and the files seem to miss even there.

At this point I'm just wondering if I'm looking in the right direction: It seems inconceivable, that it is impossible to have a documentation showing file level docblocks, due to major regressions and bugs in phpDocumentor 2.

If I'm really on the wrong track, please suggest me how to get a valuable documentation out of my PHP project. If I'm on the right track, please help me to understand what important part in the puzzle I'm missing.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @brandon yes, by leaving phpdocumentor behind and going with doxygen.